# CSS to display unordered list horizontally in IE 6 and 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

I've created a template for [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info) ([see it in action here](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/websvn)) and have worked hard to make it use web standards and validate. It looks great in most browsers, but as I feared, IE 6 and IE 7 can't quite hack it. In my case, the problem is that they refuse to render the unordered list for my navigation horizontally — they both display each `<li>` on a separate line and overflow the allotted vertical space. (IE 8 behaves correctly, and looks very close to Firefox and Safari, which was a pleasant surprise.)

I haven't been able to find a suitable solution on Google or SO. I would prefer a CSS fix, rather than JavaScript or something similar, although that's not entirely off the table. (Also, I don't care about the PNG transparency issue in IE 6 — it doesn't hurt readability at all, and IE 7 and 8 both handle it perfectly.)

---

**Edit:** Here are relevant snippets of HTML and CSS:

#### HTML

```
<ul id="links">
  <li class="diff"><a href="comp.php?repname=BYU+CocoaHeads&amp;compare[]=%2F@552&amp;compare[]=%2F@553">Compare with Previous</a></li>
  <li class="rev"><a href="revision.php?repname=BYU+CocoaHeads&amp;">Changes</a></li>
  <li class="log"><a href="log.php?repname=BYU+CocoaHeads&amp;path=%2F&amp;&amp;isdir=1">View Log</a></li>
  <li class="download"><a href="dl.php?repname=BYU+CocoaHeads&amp;path=%2F&amp;isdir=1" rel="nofollow">Download</a></li>
  <li class="svn"><a href="http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/chsvn/">SVN</a></li>
  <li class="rss"><a href="rss.php?repname=BYU+CocoaHeads&amp;path=%2F&amp;isdir=1">RSS feed</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
#links {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/bg-gray-light.png) repeat-x 0 top;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #a1a5a9;
}

#links li {
    font-size: 110%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 5px 4px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

---

**Edit:** Now that I've found a solution, the linked page won't (shouldn't?) misbehave any more in this situation, but will continue to be publicly available.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be adding it to the WebSVN trunk soon. I just need to polish up some colors and table headers on a few pages, but I'm pretty happy with it overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that IE 6 and 7 don't implement `inline-block` as expected. Looks like I found a good solution, though... Using the following CSS works for those browsers, and preserves the correct formatting in newer browsers:

```
#links {
    padding: 0 0 4px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/bg-gray-light.png) repeat-x 0 top;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #a1a5a9;
}

#links li {
    font-size: 110%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 5px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

* html #links li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I despise IE hacks.... I'm strongly considering including [Pushup](http://www.pushuptheweb.com/) in my template.

Comment: In IE6/7, `inline-block` only works on elements that are inline by default (anchors, spans).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in IE8 with compatability mode.

The only potential problem I can see is you don't specify margins on the list items. Try setting `margin:0` and see if that helps.

Comment: As I mentioned, IE 8 isn't a problem, it works fine there. It's IE 6 and 7 that have issues.

Comment: IE8 with compatibility mode == IE7. Anyway, turns out I was viewing your fixed page, which has `display:inline` on the list item.

Comment: Touché. I realized I had modified it and reverted it for now. Glad to hear that "IE7" renders it properly as well. Removing my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Assigning `float:left` to the li elements should work, IIRC.